# How to access files phtml of Magento

Tags: php, magento

I need help because I didn't find a way to access some files on Magento. For example, I accessed the **Magento** home page, went to *CMS* section -> *Pages* -> *Manage Content*.

On the left sidebar I clicked on Content and in some cases I found the following code:
*{{block type="core/template" template="cms/home.phtml"}}*

My question is this:
How can I access the home.pthml file? Can I access it and other files (the entire structure of files) from Magento or I need something else?

Comment: You can open that file in your fav editor. The file is located at `app/design/frontend/[theme]/[theme default]/template/cms/home.phtml`

Comment: But I haven't installed Magento on my computer, I just have the credentials to access the website. What should I do now? Do I have to install Magento? Or something else?

Comment: Please ask them to give credential of FTP or something else using you can access file system. This is only way.

Comment: Is it the only way? From the website? Or using something else?

Comment: This is standard way in market may extension available but those are not secured and some time also cause the permission issue. so i personally suggest you that do not use those extension.

Comment: This is standard way in market may extension available but those are not secured and some time also cause the permission issue. so i personally suggest you that do not use those extension.

Comment: I asked for ftp credentials, but the website is not managed via ftp, just through magento backend. The main problem is that I cannot access some file from the section below and I don't know what I can do

Comment: 1st you check file is located there or not
2nd thing check file permission (it required `644` permission)

Comment: 1st you check file is located there or not
2nd thing check file permission (it required `644` permission)

Answer (score 0):

Default Magento dosent provide any such functionality as it may break security.
But you can try http://ext.topmage.com/Magpleasure_Filesystem.html - It may solve your problem,
But only after doing research that will your site be secured or not.